# What is this component in a power supply?

Tags: power-supply, filter, inductor, rectifier, power-factor-correction

We bought a Cisco 6500 series 6 kW PSU and took it apart. This is a module connected immediately to the inputs of the power supply unit. Does anyone know what it does?

[image]

Comment: That whole module is a mains input filter board with fuses and protection for overvoltake surge events. The answer that was deleted was correct.

Answer (score 1):

Without part numbers we can't know for sure what some of the components are. And without a schematic we can't know how they are connected, so we can only make a guess as to what they are doing.

Even so, we can make a guess based on experience that is probably pretty close to the truth.

Staring from the top...

I first see two fat white cans that look like gas discharge tubes. They would be used for lightening or other over voltage protection.

Next to those I see some large orange parts. These could either be...

1. Ceramic X/Y capacitors for EMI filtering.
2. Or they could be MOVs (Metal Oxide Varistors), which would be for over voltage protection.  These are typically what are inside surge protectors.

Next, I see four long white components, which are almost certainly fuses.

Next there are eight large components consisting of green metal rings with red wire wrapped around them. These are inductors. They would most likely be used for EMI filtering.

All of the blue components are probably capacitors. The rectangular ones are probably film capacitors, and the smaller disc shaped ones are probably ceramic capacitors. These would be used as part of the EMI filter.

Answer (score -3):

Dual AC input power supply, When both inputs are at 220vAC then the output is 6KW. When both inputs are active but at least one is operating at 110 vAC, or a single input is active and running from 220 VAC source, the unit is capable of providing 3KW output power.

Comment: This is not the power supply. This is just a part of it, the filter between the actual power supply module and mains input.